# Android Kotlin AutoCompleteTextView item shows whole item Object when clicked

Tags: android, kotlin

So I have an AutoCompleteTextView that its dropdownlist populated with data from an array of object that formed from two different arrays by using the `zip` function.

What I want is that when each item of the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown item is clicked, it'll return one of the attribute of the clicked item object.

(This question is kind of similar with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535545/kotlin-autocompletetextview-adapter-item-selected-giving-different-value) question, however I still do not understand what to do even after reading the comments).

This is the snippet code from the Fragment where AutoCompleteTextView `newProcodeEditFormEditText` is declared :

```
 val procodeRecommendationList = allProductCodeList.zip(allProductNameList)
            .map { (allProductCodeList, allProductNameList) -> ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass(allProductCodeList, allProductNameList) }

        //This is where the created list of object being logged
        Log.i("Order", "Created List of objects: $procodeRecommendationList")


        //Set up adapter for these recommender
        val recommendedProductNameListAdapter = ArrayAdapter((activity as AppCompatActivity), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, allProductNameList)
        val recommendedProductCodeListAdapter = ProcodeRecommendationAdapter(activity as AppCompatActivity, R.layout.procode_recommendation_list_item_layout, procodeRecommendationList.toTypedArray())

        newProcodeEditFormEditText.threshold = 1
        newProductNameEditFormEditText.threshold = 1


        //Connect the adapter to each editText
        newProcodeEditFormEditText.setAdapter(recommendedProductCodeListAdapter)
        newProductNameEditFormEditText.setAdapter(recommendedProductNameListAdapter)


        //This is the onclick listener for the items in the AutoCompleteTextView Dropdown
        newProcodeEditFormEditText.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position)
            Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Selected : ".plus(selectedItem), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            Log.i("Order", "Selected item: ${selectedItem}")

        }
```

This is the created List of object `procodeRecommendationList` as shown in the LogCat:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And this is what the clicked item returned as shown in the LogCat (Stored in the variable `selectedItem` ):

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

As expected, it shown in the AutoCompleteTextView like this:
[![enter image description here][4]][4]

And this is the Custom adapter i use for showing the items in the AutoCompleteTextView Dropdown:

```
  class ProcodeRecommendationAdapter(private val c: Context,
                                   @LayoutRes private val layoutResource: Int,
                                   private val items: Array<ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass>)
    : ArrayAdapter<ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass>(c, layoutResource, items) {

    var filteredRecommendations: List<ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass> = listOf()

    override fun getCount(): Int = filteredRecommendations.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass = filteredRecommendations[position]

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val view = convertView ?: LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(layoutResource, parent, false)

        view.tvProcode.text = filteredRecommendations[position].procode
        view.tvProname.text = filteredRecommendations[position].productName

        return view
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return object : Filter() {
            override fun publishResults(charSequence: CharSequence?, filterResults: FilterResults) {
                @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
                filteredRecommendations = filterResults.values as List<ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass>
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun performFiltering(charSequence: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
                val queryString = charSequence?.toString()?.toLowerCase()

                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = if (queryString == null || queryString.isEmpty())
                    items.asList()
                else
                    items.filter {
                        it.procode?.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)!!.contains(queryString)
                    }

                return filterResults
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the data class I use:

```
 data class ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass(
    val procode: String?,
    val productName: String?
)
```

So far it has no problem in populating the AutoCompleteTextView dropdown items.

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

What I want is that I want to get the `procode` attribute so it'll only show `0100009` in the AutoCompleteTextView instead of `ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass(procode=123, productName=namehere)` when the item is clicked.

How can I achieve something like that? Where should I change in the adapter code? If There's any detail I miss, just let me know!

**Edit:**

If anyone needs the AutoCompleteTextview item layout, here:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvProcode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvProname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvProcode" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select any item from `AutoCompleteTextView`  it will be returning object of  `ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass`

You need to access it like below code

```
newProcodeEditFormEditText.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as ProcodeRecommendationListDataClass
            Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Selected : ".plus(selectedItem.procode), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            Toast.makeText((activity as AppCompatActivity), "Selected : ".plus(selectedItem.productName), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            newProcodeEditFormEditText.setText(selectedItem.procode)
            Log.i("Order", "Selected item: ${selectedItem}")

        }
```

Comment: Whoa many thanks dude! How this does not came across my mind .... Anyway you should edit your answer by adding `newProcodeEditFormEditText.setText(selectedItem.procode)`  below those two`Toast.makeText(...)`  lines so it'll help other users in the future